# How to Iterate across records in a MySql Database using Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a customer with a very small set of data and records that I'd normally just serialize to a data file and be done but they want to run extra reports and have expandability down the road to do things their own way. The MySQL database came up and so I'm adapting their Java POS (point of sale) system to work with it.

I've done this before and here was my approach in a nutshell for one of the tables, say Customers:

I setup a loop to store the primary key into an arraylist then setup a form to go from one record to the next running SQL queries based on the PK. The query would pull down the fname, lname, address, etc. and fill in the fields on the screen.

I thought it might be a little clunky running a SQL query each time they click Next. So I'm looking for another approach to this problem. Any help is appreciated! I don't need exact code or anything, just some concepts will do fine

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the solution you suggest yourself is not very good not only because you run SQL query every time a button is pressed, but also because you are iterating over primary keys, which probably are not sorted in any meaningful order...

What you want is to retrieve a certain number of records which are sorted sensibly (by first/last name or something) and keep them as a kind of cache in your ArrayList or something similar... This can be done quite easily with SQL. When the user starts iterating over the results by pressing "Next", you can in the background start loading more records.

The key to keep usability is to load some records before the user actually request them to keep latency small, but keeping in mind that you also don't want to load the whole database at once....

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking along these lines too and just bouncing ideas around in my head. I'm with you on loading maybe a hundred records at a time or something like that and once the user advances so far in the list, like selecting record 76/100 then start loading the next 100. I'll ask the client how they want it sorted, your right, pulling by PK probably won't make the most sense. At least pull by name or something more usable

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at indexing your database. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=377652

Comment: Thanks, it's been indexed by lname

Answer (score 0):

Use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jpa-137156.html) with the built in Hibernate provider. If you are not familiar with one or both, then download NetBeans - it includes a very easy to follow tutorial you can use to get up to speed. Managing lists of objects is trivial with the new JPA and you won't find yourself reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Looked at the link, great stuff! For this app I want to do it by hand to have the experience interacting directly with the database rather than use prebuilt code. I've had some SQL experience so writing queries, indexing, inserts, etc, I'll figure it out, but I appreciate the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

the key concept here is *pagination*.

Let's say you set your page size to 10. This means you select 10 records from the database, in a certain order, so your query should have an `order by` clause and a `limit` clause at the end. You use this resultset to display the form while the users navigates with Previous/Next buttons.

When the user navigates out of the page then you fetch an other page.

https://www.google.com/search?q=java+sql+pagination